# What does the option -9 mean for killall?

Tags: shell, kill, options

I saw the command `killall -9` but there is not such a option in the man page.

So now I'm a bit confused: what does `-9` option mean?

Comment: Be careful (ab)using the killall command as the potencial for doing damage is far greater.

Comment: synomous for `killall -ftw` as in *for the win*  :)

Answer (score 10):

(I assume you're talking about the [Linux `killall` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/killall.1.html).)

The option `-9` is listed in a generic way under `-SIGNAL`. The description specified that

> Signals can be specified either by name (e.g. `-HUP` or `-SIGHUP`) or by number (e.g. `-1`) or by option `-s`.

So you can use `killall -9` or `killall -s 9` to send signal number 9, `killall -42` or `killall -s 42` to send signal number 42, etc. You can use `killall -KILL` or `killall -s KILL` to send the KILL signal, etc.

On traditional and modern Unix systems and on most POSIX systems, signal number 9 is the kill signal. On many systems you can use `kill -l 9` to list the signal name corresponding to number 9; in bash, `kill -l` lists the recognized signal names with their corresponding numbers.

Answer (score 7):

This sends the `SIGKILL` (9) signal to *all* processes. A process ***can not*** intercept this signal, and is immediately killed. This means no process can clean up after itself, and even system critical processes will get killed with no contemplation.

Its single process `kill -9 pid` equivalent is **very strongly discouraged** for exactly the reason given above, `killall` is much more dangerous.

Always remember that Unix/Linux does exactly as told, even if the command is destructive. You, the system administrator, are in *complete* control. With awesome power comes great responsibility.

Answer (score 4):

It sends SIGKILL to an process (or multiple with killall).

> **SIGKILL** - The SIGKILL signal forces the process to stop executing immediately. The program cannot ignore this signal. This process does not get to clean-up either.

http://www.linux.org/threads/kill-commands-and-signals.4423/