# Why should I not use 'kill -9' / SIGKILL

Tags: process, kill

*Posting this question because I was surprised to not find it directly answered; apologies if this is a duplicate - I did look!*

I have heard that `kill -9` or `kill -SIGKILL` is bad, but I don't understand why. If I shouldn't `kill -9` what *should* I do to kill a process?

Comment: The premise of the question is wrong. SIGKILL is just a tool. It is recommended in some situations and not recommended in other situations (as are all other tools).

Comment: @kubanczyk sure, but it's an oft-misapplied tool, and used without understanding it's purpose. I've seen many threads where A says "*Just `kill -9` it*", OP says "*great, that worked! I'll remember that from now on!*", and B comes in to warn "*wait `kill -9` is dangerous!*" only after the fact.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`SIGKILL` pulls the rug out from your running process, terminating it immediately. For very simple programs this is fine; in practice however there are very few "simple" programs.

Under the covers even trivial-seeming programs do all sorts of transactional work that they need to clean up from before terminating (think of the `finally` block in Java and other programming languages), such as closing resource handles, deleting temporary files, and flushing data from memory to disk. You cannot anticipate when a program might be doing something like this.

If you're lucky you won't notice anything amiss if you send a `SIGKILL`, but you can't be lucky forever, and you may not know anything's gone wrong until it's too late to recover what's been lost.

You should almost never need to send a `SIGKILL`, and you should be sure you've exhausted your alternatives before doing so. In many cases rebooting (which will eventually send `SIGKILL`s to misbehaving programs) is safer than manually sending a `SIGKILL` yourself. I can probably count on one hand the number of times I've *needed* to send a `SIGKILL` (and likely all of my own making).

Generally speaking you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (which sends the foreground process a `SIGINT`) or `SIGTERM` (as in "terminate") to instruct a process to stop what it's doing and exit.

Some further reading:

- [Differences between `kill` signals](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/251267/19157)
- [What does `-9` mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/254496/19157)
- [How to terminate a process "for good"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28572/19157)
- [Appropriate order to send different `kill` signals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/690415/113632)
- [Useless Use of `cat` award page also discusses `kill -9`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#kill)