# What is the `-KILL` option in `pkill` command

Tags: man, pkill

I have found a way to logout any user by using the command line. By executing the command `pkill -KILL -u <username>`, I can now log myself out from the session I have entered. 
My question is that why there is no description about `-KILL` switch or option available neither in `man pkill` nor in `pkill --help`. 
I am using `Ubuntu Mate 16.04`. Thanck you very much in advance.

Comment: That's an extraordinarily bad way to log out. See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281439/why-should-i-not-use-kill-9-sigkill

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-KILL` argument is telling `pkill` which signal to send to all of the processes identified by the other arguments.  So you are sending SIGKILL which is a very very unclean way do do what you appear to be trying to do.  You probably want to send SIGHUP (with `-HUP`) or SIGTERM (with `-TERM` or omitting it, as SIGTERM is the default signal for `kill`/`pkill`).

To simplify, when a process receives `SIGTERM` from the kernel, it is being told: *"you need to go away now. Clean up after yourself and self-terminate"*.  Most well-designed programs will upon receiving this signal promptly and sanely close themselves.

When a process receives `SIGHUP`, it is being told: *"Hey, whoever you were talking to just hung up"*.  While this was historically used for serial connections which were prone to unexpected disconnections, this is often used as a signal to have a shell's job control to spin down all pending processes (or ofttimes for a daemon to reinitialize itself or re-parse its configuration file).

When a process receives `SIGKILL`, the kernel (metaphorically) walks up behind it and shoots it in the back of the head.  On one hand:  no fuss, no muss.  On the other hand:  there may be a huge mess to clean up.

A `KILL`ed process has no chance to clean up any open temporary files; any unflushed cached data are likely to be lost, and so forth.  Therefore, do **not** send `SIGKILL` unless you *really* have to.

Comment: Note that SIGTERM is not _handled_ by commands by default. The stdio buffers for instance are not flushed by default upon SIGTERM. The commands will have to actively install a handler on SIGTERM for that. On GNU/Linux systems see `ps -eo caught,pid,args | gawk -v t="$(kill -l TERM)" 'and(strtonum("0x"$1), 2**(t-1))'` for a list of processes that do have a handler on SIGTERM.

Comment: note `kill` and `pkill` will send `SIGTERM` by default.  try `pkill foo` before sending `pkill -KILL foo`.

Comment: While it is true that SIGTERM is the default, I prefer to explicitly state which signal I wish to send when using KILL as a self-imposed sanity check.  It also makes editing the command line / script to send non-TERM signals easier on later iterations if needed.

Comment: If the goal is logging out users, then really a `SIGHUP` should be sent before sending either of those.