# lock file not removed when trap is inside an "if"

Tags: bash, trap, lock

I put my trap inside an `if`, run the script, and after that second execution, it warns that lock file is held (ok). But when I `kill -9` the running PID, the lockfile is not removed.

When I move trap before the `if` (what you can see now commented below):

1. then when I `kill -9 PID`, lockfile is deleted (ok)
2. but when I run additional executions the scripts, only first one warns because after this first-additional run, the lockfile is removed by trap on `EXIT`!

How to get the trap inside `if` to remove the lockfile on `kill -9` of the script?

```bash
lockfile=/tmp/localfile
#trap 'rm -f "$lockfile"; exit $?' INT TERM EXIT KILL
if ( set -o noclobber; echo "$$" > "$lockfile") 2> /dev/null;
then
    trap 'rm -f "$lockfile"; exit $?' INT TERM EXIT KILL
    while true
    do
        ls -ld ${lockfile}
        sleep 1
    done
    rm -f "$lockfile"
    trap - INT TERM EXIT
else
    echo "Failed to acquire lockfile: $lockfile."
    echo "Held by $(cat $lockfile)"
fi
```

Comment: if you shoot the script with `SIGKILL`, i.e. `kill -9`, it should be killed _without_ getting a chance to react to the signal. Are you sure you didn't just use `kill` (without `-9`) in the case where the trap worked?

Answer (score 0):

`kill -KILL` (or `kill -9`) kills the process without it being able to clean up.  The `SIGKILL` signal is non-trappable by design.

Use a plain `kill` (sends `TERM` by default) instead.

See also: [Why should I not use 'kill -9' / SIGKILL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281439/why-should-i-not-use-kill-9-sigkill)

Comment: thank you, I was thinking about a case that someone kills my process with -9 and the lock is not removed...

Comment: @DonJ If someone kills your script with `SIGKILL`, then you can't do anything to catch that.

Comment: Cleanup redundant lock files on initialisation? Ahh, how to determine if lock files are redundant? On a local-only app you should be able to detect if the process is already running or not but, what about a network application? network-root-user on each machine? Makes it complicated.

Comment: @Willtech Yes, the general case is not easy.