# Delete "PID killed" message

Tags: bash, shell-script, process, kill

How can I delete the message of kill -9?

```
$ kill -9 PID
PID killed    Process_name
```

The result must be

```
$kill -9 PID
$
```

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281439/why-should-i-not-use-kill-9-sigkill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[disown](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html#Job-Control-Builtins) the pid/job:

```
disown $PID
kill -9 $PID
```

Comment: or `set +m; kill -9 $PID; set -m`, but you shouldn't use `kill -9` to start with.