# command to kill all process by name

Tags: linux, bash

I have many processes running by name gunicorn

```
ubuntu   23884  0.0  7.1 190092 71980 ?        S    Sep10   0:01 gunicorn: worker [ll1]
ubuntu   23885  0.0  6.8 187120 69128 ?        S    Sep10   0:01 gunicorn: worker [ll1]
ubuntu   23886  0.0  7.1 189800 71712 ?        S    Sep10   0:01 gunicorn: worker [ll1]
```

I want to kill all proccess by name gunicorn.Currently i am able to kill only one process by this script at a time.

```
#!/bin/bash
pid=`ps ax | grep gunicorn | awk '{split($0,a," "); print a[1]}' | head -n 1`
echo $pid
kill $pid
echo "killed gunicorn"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the kill all command and what signal you want to send:

```
killall -<signal> gunicorn
```

You can also use -v to output more information of what it is doing:

```
killall -v -<signal> gunicorn
```

Or to use a script like you are doing you could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for pid in `pidof gunicorn`; do 
    kill -<signal> $pid;
    echo "killed gunicorn [$pid]"; 
done
```

<signal>:

[image]

Comment: Related: [Why should I not use 'kill -9' / SIGKILL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281439/why-should-i-not-use-kill-9-sigkill)

Comment: @Kusalananda, I did say kill all command and what signal you want to send.  Or he can leave off the signal and I believe the default is sending a SIGTERM, but I believe when the operating system is closing down I think it sends out SIGTERM and waits and then sends out a SIGKILL.  I will modify my answer and replace 9 with <signal>.

Answer (score 4):

```
pkill -f gunicorn
echo "killed gunicorn"
```

That will kill any process that has the name `gunicorn` on the line and print the `killed gunicorn` message.

Answer (score 1):

There are many way to do this but let's focus on the main two that I know:

##### Using `ps` and `xargs`

With `grep`:

```bsh
ps -ef | grep '<pattern>' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -r kill -9
```

With `awk`:

```bsh
ps -ef | awk '/<pattern>/ && !/awk/ {print $2}' | xargs -r kill -9
```

These commands will kill all the process that match with the `<pattern>`

So your script will be like:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
ps -ef | grep 'gunicorn' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -r kill -9

[ $? -eq 0 ] && echo 'killed gunicorn'
```

Or,

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
ps -ef | awk '/gunicorn/ && !/awk/ {print $2}' | xargs -r kill -9

[ $? -eq 0 ] && echo 'killed gunicorn'
```

##### Using `ps` and `for`

```bsh
for pid in `ps ax | grep '<pattern>' | awk ' { print $1;}'`; do 
  kill -9 $pid
done
```

This also will kill all the process that match with the `<pattern>`

So your script will be like:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for pid in `ps ax | grep 'gunicorn' | awk ' { print $1;}'`; do 
  kill -9 $pid
done

[ $? -eq 0 ] && echo 'killed gunicorn'
```